# React error for useEffect Hook conditional call when there is no such conditional call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React is complaining about code below, saying it `useEffect` is being called conditionally:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const documentCounts = {};
  const invertedIndexes = {};

  for (const term of []) {
    if (!invertedIndexes[term]) continue;
    // The offending code is the loop below
    for (const arr of invertedIndexes[term]) {
      const documentIndex = arr[0];
      if (!documentCounts[documentIndex]) documentCounts[documentIndex] = 1;
      else ++documentCounts[documentIndex];
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {});

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```
React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return? react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

But to me it seems like there is no conditional call to `useEffect` - the loop just modifies local variables. Does anyone happen to know what the problem here is?

(the pointless variables are what I boiled down my original code down to to try to pinpoint the issue)

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-diffie-z7edc

Comment: maybe it's need `useState`

Comment: You are using useEffect without doing anything inside that, remove useEffect, presently you don't need it. Also to useEffect, you have to provide a dependent state, when this state changes, then useEffect will trigger again. Something like this  useEffect(() => {
    doSometing();
  }, [dependentState]);

Comment: The content inside `useEffect` is not relevant - the problem is that React is complaining the *order* of the hook *call* is not the same on every render when, according to what I'm seeing, it is. Adding anything inside the `useEffect` call won't fix the error

Comment: Move useEffect to before for loop then it will be fixed

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of it before but this definitely fixed it! Though the question remains as to why React is complaining the original order

Comment: this seems like a bug in the react error message to me. I would post this in the react github

Answer (score 2):

Check official documentation on the hooks: [Always use Hooks at the top level of your React function.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Comment: When they say "top level", I believe they mean it in a "not within anything such as inner-functions, loops, conditions, etc." sense, rather than literally "at the top"

Comment: @platizin nope they mean not inside loops functions etc because these are lifecycle methods and manipulating them inside conditions or other functions in not how they work.