# is it safe to ignore react's warning about calling the useState hook conditionally when only the parameter is conditional?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am creating a calendar date selection function component for assigning days to schedules in my React app and I wanted to be able to pre-populate calendar with the existing data so that it could be modified by the user.

This is what I have so far:

```
const initialOptions: { [key: string]: number[] } = {};

for (const option of Object.keys(props.options)) {
    const dates = props.options[option].dates;
    initialOptions[option] = dates ? dates : [];
}

const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState(initialOptions);
```

However, when I try and render the page, I get this:

```
React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

After reading through the react [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation), I didn't see anything that indicated that react was depending on the *value* of the parameter to "associate local state with [my useState() call]". All it really said was...

> As long as the order of the Hook calls is the same between renders, React can associate some local state with each of them.

So why is react complaining at me when I am calling `useState()` in top-level react code that is outside of any conditional statements or functions as per their own rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56582778) that basically said calls to react hooks need to be *before* any control structures, *even if they are unrelated* were what pointed me in the right direction.

The answer provided in the comments was not quite satisfactory though since I needed to process the inital value of `selectedDates` **if** an initial value was provided and have that available **before** I called `useState()` in order to pass it as a parameter.

Despite being perplexed by this and the somewhat nonsensical nature of this solution (order shouldn't matter with two barely-related pieces of code, *right*?), I managed to refactor my logic such that it both stopped react from complaining *AND* allowed me to still conditionally set the `selectedDates` in my react calendar component.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
const initialOptions: { [key: string]: number[] } = {};

Object.entries(props.options).forEach(value => {
    const [id, options] = value;
    if (options.dates) {
        initialOptions[id] = options.dates;
    }
});

const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState(initialOptions);
```

As someone who isn't that familiar with the internals of react, it seems that either:

- the react team got something wrong when writing the ESLint plugin for the react hook rules, or
- there was a functional limitation in how ESLint works that doesn't allow for a more specific/accurate check, causing the developers to go with a "better safe than sorry" approach by using a less specific check that still caught rule violations as well as edge cases like this one

So overall, my conclusion is, by replacing my `for` loop with a call to `.forEach()`, the ESLint
plugin saw my loop as a *function* rather than a control structure/conditional and allowed my code to pass the test and run without issue.

Now, [as a self-described "junior" react developer](https://pics.me.me/junior-react-developer-senior-react-developer-34639076.png), i'm pretty sure that tricking ESLint into not giving an error like this is not a good long-term solution. Ideally ESLint rules probably need updating to better check for improper use of conditionals, and/or the react docs should be updated with an example for how to conditionally set a hook's default value in a way that doesn't violate the rules of react hooks.

**EDIT:** I have created an [issue](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/2251) for the react documentation in order to find out what a good long-term solution to this would be and get the documentation and/or ESLint plugins updated if necessary

Comment: probably, it's a bug in ESLint plugin. something quite similar to your case has already led [to complex code update](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14362) in January. So I believe this case may also lead to plugin's patching. Good to know you've created issue into their repo. Maybe better to include code sample.

Comment: I linked to this post in the issue so if any of the devs are curious, all the relevant code samples are accessible

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore the warning that means that you are **setting your expectations wrong** on how your `Component`'s code will be executed during renderings.

Just by looking at `initialOptions`, you can see that the initial value is based on incoming `props`. In React when the `props` change your `Component` gets re-rendered, the `initialOptions` is re-evaluated **BUT it's NOT** updated again by `useState(initialOptions)`.

Sure you can say: "but my useState(initialOptions) is not wrapped around any condition!". While that is absolutely true, you didn't inform React that `selectedDates` needs to be updated between renders. It's value is still the first initial value when the Component was rendered first time.

You need to move the `foreach` logic into a `useEffect` with dependency to `props.options`.

Example based on your code:

```
const initialOptions: { [key: string]: number[] } = {};
const [selectedDates, setSelectedDates] = useState(initialOptions);

useEffect(() => {

// Here it's okay to have an optional condition!
if (!props.options.length) { return false; }

const newOptions = [];

Object.entries(props.options).forEach(value => {
    const [id, options] = value;
    if (options.dates) {
        newOptions[id] = options.dates;
    }
});

setSelectedDates(newOptions);

}, [props.options]);
```

I've prepared a sandbox example which demonstrates why the rule "Only Call Hooks at the Top Level - Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions." must be respected https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-meadow-xvy50t?file=/src/Component.js  <-- click the body of the page repeatedly and notice that the component doesn't update.